# Dynamically place a button/div on the top right corner of all images in the page using css/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to place a close button over each image in a web page. I can't place the image correctly over on the top right corner of the image.

```js
function init_close_button(){
 var trc=document.getElementsByClassName('top_right_corner');
 for(var i=0;i<trc.length;i++){
  trc[i].onclick=function(e){
   e.target.parentNode.remove();
  }
 }
}

function loadtest(){
var a=document.createElement('div');
a.innerHTML="WindowLoaded";
document.body.appendChild(a);
}
window.onload=function(){
loadtest();
init_close_button();
}
```

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
    width:'33%';
    
}
.content .top_right_corner {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.top_right_corner{
  border:solid 1px blue;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.content:hover .top_right_corner{
  border:solid 1px red;
}
img{
  border:solid 2px yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="content">
    <div class="top_right_corner">click to close</div>
    <img width="150" height="150"/>
</span>
<span class="content">
<img width="150" height="150"/>
<div class="top_right_corner">delete</div>
</span>
<span class="content">
<img width="150" height="150"/>
<div class="top_right_corner">close this</div>
</span>

<span class="content">
<img width="150" height="150"/>
<div class="top_right_corner">close this</div>
</span>
```

I have no problem in hiding/removing the image. I need some help to place the close button/text on corner of the images.

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS of `.content` and `.content .top_right_corner`. Absolute positioning works with (inline-)block containers only.

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.content .top_right_corner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 52px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left;` in the `span` and `right:3px; top:3px;` in the `div`

```js
function init_close_button(){
 var trc=document.getElementsByClassName('top_right_corner');
 for(var i=0;i<trc.length;i++){
  trc[i].onclick=function(e){
   e.target.parentNode.remove();
  }
 }
}

function loadtest(){
var a=document.createElement('div');
a.innerHTML="WindowLoaded";
document.body.appendChild(a);
}
window.onload=function(){
loadtest();
init_close_button();
}
```

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
.content .top_right_corner {
    position: absolute;
    top:3px;
    right:3px;
}
.top_right_corner{
  border:solid 1px blue;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.content:hover .top_right_corner{
  border:solid 1px red;
}
img{
  border:solid 2px yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="content">
    <div class="top_right_corner">click to close</div>
    <img width="150" height="150"/>
</span>
<span class="content">
<img width="150" height="150"/>
<div class="top_right_corner">delete</div>
</span>
<span class="content">
<img width="150" height="150"/>
<div class="top_right_corner">close this</div>
</span>

<span class="content">
<img width="150" height="150"/>
<div class="top_right_corner">close this</div>
</span>
```